# Symfony session doesn't work on ubuntu

Tags: php, symfony

Hello I have a problem with storing data to session using Symfony.

Here is my code:

```
public function currentAction() {
        $session = $this->get('session');
        $userArray = $session->get('test');
        if($session->get('test') == null) {
            $userArray = User::toArray($this->getUser());
            $session->set('test', $userArray);
        }

        $this->setModel($userArray);
        $this->sendResponse();
}
```

When I try to execute the code for the secound time the $session->get('test') still returns null. Can anybody helps me?
I also use (use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session;) from the beginning of my controller class.

Comment: Hmm, strange...
Try to add default param for session like $session = $this->get('session', null);
and debug the session result before send response

Comment: In my windows 8.1 it is work and I don't understand why on ubuntu not...

Comment: On ubuntu i haven't permission to write on session folder

Comment: Change permission for var/sesisons folder. :)

Comment: Here's how you can fix these permissions: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/file_permissions.html#using-acl-on-a-system-that-supports-setfacl-linux-bsd

Comment: And how should I have use session for multiple controllers???